# Looking for a explanation with params in Statsmodels-get_robustcov_results

Tags: python, statsmodels

When I am studying the 'RegressionResult.get_robustcov_results, I feel a little confused about the statements of the 'cluster' part in the document.
Here is what in the document about the 'cluster ':

> 'cluster' and required keyword *groups*, **integer** group indicator
> *groups* array_like, **integer** (required): index of clusters or groups

the following are my concerns:

1. what does the **integer** mean in this statement? I have tried using a float data to derive my results, it still worked. This makes me curious about what the “integer” here actually imply within the document. Besides, why not “group indicator” in the text.
2. The **groups** is used as the index of groups or clusters, the clusters and groups are mentioned simultaneously. However, to my understanding, I cannot really tell the difference between these two nouns in this setting.

Could anybody please give me a further explanation on the above questions?

At last, lacking of the example code of 'get_robustcov_results' method, my code is presenting below, I want to get a confirmation of my writing style. (even it runs well)

```
results. get_robustcov_results(“cluster”, groups = DataFrame['var'] )
```

(Assuming: results is the result obtained from my nonrobust regressionx var is the one which I want to use to correct my SE estimation.)

Thanks.

Comment: you can specify this, cov_type, cov_kwds, in the `fit` method. get_robustcov_results was the initial interface but is now mainly an internal method.

Comment: to 2. cluster and groups are synonym and mean the same thing. The literature uses "cluster robust" as term, statsmodels uses `groups` as name to indicate cluster or group membership.

Comment: Thanks for @Josef 's suggestions.  Would you mind giving me a further explanation about the word **integer** in the first question?

Comment: I guess the integer requirement is outdated. AFAICS, if the `groups` indicator for "cluster" is not integer dtype, then the code converts internally to integers. AFAICS, it should also work with strings.